# Why DataTable in SSIS script task loses data?

Tags: c#, ssis, ssis-2012

I tried to make this SSIS package as below:

1. Create an Object type variable `var` and an Execute SQL Task, inside the component make proper configs so a table with some rows are filled into `var`.
2. Create a Script Task and connect it after Execute SQL Task, set `var` as read only variable. inside the script add below code:

```
DataTable tb = new DataTable();
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
adapter.Fill(tb, Dts.Variables["User::var"].Value); 
Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
```

Place a break point on the last line.

3. Copy-paste the previous Script Task and connect it after it.

So the overall progress is generate a dataset -> Read into DataTable -> Read again into DataTable.

Debug result shows in step 2 the row count and dataset is expected, but in Step 3, all data in dataTable is cleared, leaving an empty dataTable with only table structure exists.

What's the reason for this result?

Comment: Are you trying to read twice from the same datatable that you populated once?  I have had this issue and there was a workaround but I found it easier to just populate the datatable again vs trying to do the workaround.